# Intermittent Rails mailer 'missing template' issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I say intermittent, but it's really like 50% of the time. Here's what I'm using:

- Rails 4.2.1
- Sidekiq 3.4.1

I have a mailer that runs from ActiveJob, and half the time it is unable to find its associated template:

Missing template notifier/claim_email with "mailer". Searched in:
  * "notifier"

The template is most definitely present and named properly:

$ ls app/views/notifier/

claim_email.html.erb
claim_email.txt.erb

Code:

```
def claim_email(subject, message)

    @message = message
    mail(
      to: %Q{<#{ENV['DEFAULT_EMAIL']}>},
      subject: subject,
    )
end
```

Template:

```
<%= @message %>
```

I've also tried adding the :body option to send directly, but it inexplicably still tries to use the template(?!) I've restarted the app multiple times to no avail. This also *always* works in development. I'm baffled as to what could be happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was having the same issue as the person in this question:

[Rails.root points to the wrong directory in production during a Resque job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820899/rails-root-points-to-the-wrong-directory-in-production-during-a-resque-job)

My sidekiq jobs were not being properly restarted on deploy, which led them to have old pathnames for templates.

Comment: When using Capistrano to deploy the app, add `gem 'capistrano-sidekiq'` to the `Gemfile`, `require 'capistrano/sidekiq'` to the `Capfile`, and if deployment crashes afterwards, add `set :rbenv_map_bins, %w(rake gem bundle ruby rails sidekiq sidekiqctl)` to `deploy.rb` (the latter as per [this comment on an issue](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq/issues/147#issuecomment-221960908)).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Restarting sidekiq solved it for me. Good luck!