# Ruby searching template on old/not existant release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, capistrano, unicorn, sentry

I'm using ruby on rails and I'm sending notifications to the user using a gem called UserNotifier.

Lately I tried to change the templates of those notifications, but the sent emails did not change at all. I'm using sentry for checking on some events and errors then an odd thing happened, the templates are searched on and OLD and deleted release.

---

**SENTRY LOG**

Missing template user_notifier/mailer/confirm_contribution_subject with {:locale=>[:pt], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee]}. Searched in:

"/home/folder/folder/releases/20190530165426/app/views/catarse_bootstrap"

"/home/folder/folder/releases/20190530165426/app/views"

---

I want to search on another release or even better, the **Current** one, but I don't know where this **Error Path** is saved.

Im also using sidekiq... I searched on code and on some **Path** variables but so far nothing. I'm not sure if someone changed the Capistrano default **Path**, I'm checking this now...
I'm missing something for sure...

---

[EDIT]
Capistrano realease_path is linking to the right path

[EDIT2]
I'm thinking its something about the "Unicorn"/"Nginx", maybe using an old PID worker...

Something similar to this "resque" question:
[Rails.root points to the wrong directory in production during a Resque job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820899/rails-root-points-to-the-wrong-directory-in-production-during-a-resque-job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the real problem...

There was a "Sidekiq" task running since may.
It was supposed to be restarted after every deploy, but the deploy code wasn't killing this old process.

I used this

```
ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd
```

To find all running processes and found an old "sidekiq" running since the date (20190530165426)

Killed it and "redeployed" now only using the new "sidekiq" process.